# How to send 4000+ requests in exactly 1 second?

Tags: java, jmeter, performance-testing, heap-memory, stack-memory

I have an `HTTP GET request`. I need to send the request to the application server for more than `4000` times exactly in 1 second.

I'm sending these requests using JMeter. I have taken ethereal traces every time for each test using a sniffer tool (`Wireshark`).

I have tried to achieve this from one machine, multiple machines (parallel) and even distributed mode.

Actually, JMeter results are not my concern here. The concern of this test is to see that `4000` requests are hitting the server in one second at the sniffer tool.

I have found almost `2500` request in `1 sec` in ethereal trace while using the following JMeter test plan.

```
Number of Threads= 4000
Ramp-Up Periods = 0 (Though it is depricated)
Loop count= 1
```

When I use the number of threads as `2500`, I got almost `2200 request` hitting the server in one second in the ethereal trace.

Response from the server for that request is not my concern here. I just want to make sure that `4000` request sent by `JMeter` is hitting the application server in one second.

### **UPDATE:**

**Case 1: (4000 Threads)**

```
Number of Threads= 4000
Ramp-Up Periods = 0 
Loop count= 1
```

**Output for Case 1:**

> **JMeter (View Results in Table)**: 2.225 seconds to start 4000 requests.
>
> **Ethereal trace**: 4.12 seconds for 4000 requests to hit the server.

[image]

**Case 2: (3000 Threads)**

> **JMeter (View Results in Table)**: 1.83 seconds to start 3000 requests.
>
> **Ethereal trace**: 1.57 seconds for 3000 requests to hit the server.

**Case 3: (2500 Threads)**

> **JMeter (View Results in Table)**: 1.36 seconds to start 2500 requests.
>
> **Ethereal trace**: 2.37 seconds for 2500 requests to hit the server.

**Case 4: (2000 Threads)**

> **JMeter (View Results in Table)**: 0.938 seconds to start 2000 requests.
>
> **Ethereal trace**: 1.031 seconds for 2000 requests to hit the server.

```
I have run these test from only one machine. 
No listeners added.
Non-Gui mode.
No assertions in my scripts.
Heap size: 8GB
```

So, I don't understand why my JMeter Results and ethereal traces differ from each other. I've also tried with [Synchronizing Timer](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Synchronizing_Timer) to achieve this scenario.

Since 4000 Threads is too heavy, maybe I have to test this in Distributed mode. I've also tried with distributed mode (1 master, 2 slaves). Maybe my script is wrong.

Is it possible to see in the ethereal trace that my 4000 requests hit the server in 1 second?

What will be the JMeter script to achieve this scenario in distributed mode?

Comment: As with any network test, there's always going to be problems, especially with latency - even if you could send exactly 4000 requests per second, they're going to be sent sequentially (that's just how packets get sent) and may not all hit in that second, plus processing time.

Comment: 4000 threads need 4000 stacks. At 1MB each, that's 4GB of RAM just for the stacks alone.

Comment: Must the requests open a new connection each time, or can opened sockets be reused?

Comment: Both conditions will be okay for me. But I need to see that exactly 4000 requests are hitting the server at a time (1 second) in my ethereal trace.

Comment: There's some bottleneck obviously (judging from the picture). First thing to always suspect is number of open ports. On linux/mac it's usually limited by max number of open files (which by default is quite low - 1024 I think, you can check by running `ulimit -n`). On Windows it's a combination fo open ports + "time wait" time (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa560610(v=bts.20).aspx). So the first question: are you sure your machine CAN open 4000 ports at once?

Comment: The file-max parameter in my machine was set to `500000`. I had set this value according to [this](http://tldp.org/LDP/solrhe/Securing-Optimizing-Linux-RH-Edition-v1.3/chap6sec72.html) calculation. My machine RAM is `16GB`.

Comment: Are you trying to do this from a cold start?

Comment: Yes, I haven't use any warm-up time in this specific test. But I also have tried with the ramp-up to initialize those threads but no luck.

Comment: Why `exactly`? Your requirement as stated is to be able to handle *at least* 4000 rps. So as long as you sent 4000 or more rps you have tested your requirement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about starting with whether the server is configured correctly to avoid such load.  Requests can be of any type.  If they are of static requests then work to ensure that the absolute minimum number of these hit your origin server due to caching policies or architecture, such as

- If you have returning users and no CDN, make sure your cache policy is storing at the client, expiring with your build schedule.  This avoids repeat requests from returning visitors
- If you have no returning users and no CDN, make sure that your cache policy is set to at least 120% of the maximum page to page delay visible in your logs for a given user set
- If you have a CDN, make sure all static request headers, 301 & 404 headers are set to allow your CDN to cache your requests to expire with your new build push schedule.
- If you do not have a CDN, consider a model where you place all static resources on a dedicated server where everything on that server is marked for caching at the client at a high level.  You can also front that one server with varnish or squid as a caching proxy to take the load

Utlimately I would suspect a design issue at play with this high a consistent request level.   4000 requests per second becomes 14,400,000 requests per hour and 345,600,000 per 24 hour period.

On a process basis, I would also suggest a minimum of three load generators: Two for primary load and one for a control virtual user of a single virtual user|thread for your business process.  In your current model for all on one load generator you have no control element to determine the overhead imposed by the potential overload of your load generator.  The use of the control element will help you determine if you have a load generator imposed skew in your driving of load.   Essentially, you have a resource exhausting which is adding a speed break on your load generator.   Go for a deliberate underload philosophy on your load generators.   Adding another load generator is cheaper than the expense of political capital when someone attacks your test for lack of a control element and then you need to re-run your test.   It is also far less expensive than chasing an engineering ghost which appears as a slow system but which is really an overloaded load generator

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to stick with JMeter? 
Otherwise [Httperf](https://github.com/httperf/httperf) is a decent tool and easy to use:

```
httperf --server=www.example.com --rate=4000 --num-conns=4000
```

for instance.

Hope this helps a bit, although not entirely what you asked for.

Answer (score 0):

Consider putting your HTTP Request under the [Synchronizing Timer](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Synchronizing_Timer) - this way you'll be sure your requests are kicked off at exactly the same moment.

Also 4000 threads is quite a "heavy" load so I would suggest following recommendations from the [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/9-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure) guide to get the most performance from your JMeter instance(s).

Comment: I've updated my question. I've tried with a synchronizing timer but no luck. I've already seen those suggestions you had provided.

Comment: Is it possible to achieve from the Distributed mode? If yes, what will be the JMeter script configurations?

Comment: Synchronizing Timer doesn't work in distributed mode. In fact it works, but it doesn't know anything about other slaves. If you need to do it in the distributed mode - you may need to consider threads scheduling instead (maybe in combination with local Syncronizing Timers with lesser "group by" count)

Answer (score 0):

1. If your PC is not enough, you  should use distributed testing in
   Jmeter
2. Keep in mind, that in theory you can send 4000 requests per second, 
   they will spend some time  on the way to the server, so there is
   probability that they will come not in 1 second. To avoid this, try
   to use high bandwidth lan( for example, you can host your server in
   Azure cloud and install Jmeter in cloud too. )
3. If you will have no success with JMeter try to use [Tank](https://github.com/yandex/yandex-tank) This
   tool specialized on high loading, and it should be possible to send
   even 10k requests in 1 second from 1 machine.