# Ramp up period 0 vs 1

Tags: jmeter, load-testing

What is the difference between ramp up period 1 and ramp up period 0 ?
I have Thread count 10 and while giving ramp up 0 some of my cases making null pointer exception.With ramp up 1 its working fine. With ramp up 1 it means that within 1 second 10 users will start together. What will happen for ramp up 0?

Answer (score 7):

If you set ramp-up as 0, all the threads will start at 1st second after the test has been started.  If the ramp-up period is zero, JMeter will create all the threads at **once** and send out requests **immediately**.

You can use it while you require a sudden large influx of requests in your site.

Let's say you have set it up to use 10 threads and have a ramp-up period of 0 then when you start your test run it will make 10 requests at the **exact same moment**.

Comment: And with ramp up 1, it also create 1000 threads at 1 second. That also makes sudden large influx on system. So where is the difference?

Comment: With ramp up 1, it will send 10 threads in 1 seconds and the interval between threads to reach the server is 0.1 seconds for each one. For ramp-up 0, it will send 10 threads at the exact same moment. There will be no interval in theoretically. You can check this using Table result listener and as well as Wireshark in your server end by monitoring those requests traffic. Actually, Ramp-up zero is more likely an equivalent to ramp-up 1.

Comment: Ok thats a point. Did you ever find different results between these two? In my case I got lots of exception.

Comment: What type of exception are you seeing? Maybe it's due to resource utilization fo your machine while using ramp-up value as 0. Using Ramp-up value 0 is not suggested to mimic the user load unless checking the peak scenario. You can check this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39243223/how-to-send-4000-requests-in-exactly-1-second

Comment: I much cases it was nullpointerexception. In some cases login failed etc.

Comment: Actually, I can't say the reason blindly. But I can suggest some possible workaround like check the JMeter log, Monitor these request using any network sniffer and also check your application log at the target load server. Thank you!

Comment: @Esty You will get exceptions if you provide less number of seconds as ramp up. From my experience, to achieve higher throughput, always give higher ramp up time which helps the system to process. Lesser ramp-up will crash the system and you are not replicating the real-world scenario. Also run a warm-up test before you start the actual load test. Hope this helps.

Comment: @NaveenKumarNamachivayam, thnx for your reply. Imagine a financial transaction case for 200 users working together with 10000 iterations of transaction. What ramp up would you prefer?

Comment: @Esty As you mentioned financial transaction, when the business hour starts, gradually, there will be an increase in the load. If you have the production data, it is easy to create workload. If there is no production volume available, I prefer to use stair-step ramp up. E.g. to achieve 200 users, you can inject 5 users for every 30 seconds - 60 seconds. This will give ample time to the system to process.